# Android MediaPlayer - Play sound twice while not finished

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I added click sound to my Android app, but **when I click too fast on buttons, the sound is played only once** (beacause the first play is not finished yet). **I want the sound to be played at each click**.

I would like to know what is the best way to implement the behaviour that I want ?

I put the instantiation of the MediaPlayer in the onCreate() method and play it in the onClick()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    [...]
    mpClic = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.clic);
}


vButtonLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        [...]               
        mpClic.start();
     }
});
```

- I tried to stop() / prepare() it before the play() but I get the same thing.
- I tried to instanciate a new MediaPlayer at each play, it works but I guess it is not recommended (and by the way, with this method, the sound in my activity stop if I spam the button too many times very quickly)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Check if `mpClic.isPlaying()` before `mpClic.start();` second time. [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: Ok but how can I play it a second time if it's already playing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, I reduced the lenght of my clic sound (from 0.50s to 0.17s) so it finishes to play earlier ; then I initiate 2 instances of it. If I need to play the sound and the first instance is already playing, I play the second.

```
private MediaPlayer mpClic1;
private MediaPlayer mpClic2; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    [...]
    mpClic1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.clic);
    mpClic2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.clic);
}

vButtonRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            [...]
            if(mpClic1.isPlaying())
                mpClic2.start();
            else
                mpClic1.start();
        }
    });
```

It's a workaround so if someone knows how to achieve the desire effect of replaying a MediaPlayer that is already playing, please tell it and I will put it as correct answer. :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try to:

```
vButtonLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

    if(mpClic.isPlaying()){
        mpClic.stop();
        mpClic.prepare();
     }
        mpClic.start();
     }
});
```

Comment: Tried it and it does the same thing :/

Answer (score 3):

You can just play the sound from beginning if it is already playing.

```
vButtonLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if (mpClic.isPlaying())
        {
            mpClic.seekTo(0);
        }
        else
        {
            mpClic.start();
        }
    }
});
```

Not exactly what you want but gives satisfactory result in most cases.